# Calling a JS function within jQuery(mousedown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to make a jQuery function that prints a shape into the canvas when I click on it. But jQuery doesn't seem to be calling the function *(makeCircle())* . Is there something wrong with the syntax or there something I have to do with the function outside of jQuery?

HTML Code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <canvas id = 'board' height = "600" width = "800" style="border:1px solid black";></canvas>
            <head>
        <title> Shape Drawing </title>
    <div id = "links">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "functions.js"></script>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = stylesheet href="main.css">

    </div>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id = "shapes_title"> Shapes:</h1> 
        <div id = "buttons">
        <button id = 'Circle' onclick="circleTrue()"> Circle </button>
        <button id = "Square" onclick ="squareTrue()"> Square </button>
        <button id = "Triangle" onclick="triangleTrue"> Triangle </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript/jQuery -

```
var c = document.getElementById("board");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var circle = true;
var square  = false;
var triangle = false;
var shape;

jQuery(function($) {
var currentMousePos = {x: -1, y: -1};
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;

});

});






//making circle true
function circleTrue() {
    if(circle = false) {
        circle = true;
        square = false;
        triangle = false;
    }
}
function squareTrue() {
 if(square = false) {
    circle = false;
    square = true;
    triangle = false;
}
}
function triangleTrue() {
    if(triangle = false) {
        circle = false;
        square = false;
        triangle = true;
    }
}


//making the circle (coord no)
function makeCircle() {
if(circle = true){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.stroke();
}
else{
    console.log("You have not selected circle as an object!");
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
//circle color jquery
 $("#Circle").mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css("color", "green");
 });
 $("#Circle").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css("color", 'white');
 });

$("#Square").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "green");

});
$("#Square").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "white");
});
$("#Triangle").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
});
$("#Triangle").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "white");
});
$("c").mousedown(function() {
  makeCircle();
});
});
```

Comment: What element are you trying to target with "c"?  Take the quotes off of it if you are trying to use the variable defined above it in the script

Comment: `$("c").mousedow` whats is `c` ?,there is no `c` tag in your html.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `"c"` as a selector, which doesn't find any elements with that tag name. Even if it was an ID selector `#c`, I see no elements with that ID.

Also, within `makeCircle`, you have `if(circle = true){`, which should be using `circle === true` or just `circle` instead of `circle = true`. In fact, you have a bunch of `if` statements that are like that.

Comment: I thought that was just an id. Do I have to make that "board", which is the same id as my html canvas?

Comment: @Slasher: If you want to select the element with the ID `board`, then it should be `#board`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$(c)`, without the quotes around `c`

Comment: @JamieMcElwain: True, as long as the element was found with `getElementById()`. Given the invalid HTML, I'm not certain of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct selector. As you are getting element with `var c = document.getElementById("board");` you need to use `c` variable instead of string `"c"` or use direct id #board

```js
var c = document.getElementById("board");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var circle = true;
var square  = false;
var triangle = false;
var shape;

jQuery(function($) {
var currentMousePos = {x: -1, y: -1};
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;

});

});






//making circle true
function circleTrue() {
    if(circle = false) {
        circle = true;
        square = false;
        triangle = false;
    }
}
function squareTrue() {
 if(square = false) {
    circle = false;
    square = true;
    triangle = false;
}
}
function triangleTrue() {
    if(triangle = false) {
        circle = false;
        square = false;
        triangle = true;
    }
}


//making the circle (coord no)
function makeCircle() {
if(circle = true){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.stroke();
}
else{
    console.log("You have not selected circle as an object!");
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
//circle color jquery
 $("#Circle").mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css("color", "green");
 });
 $("#Circle").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css("color", 'white');
 });

$("#Square").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "green");

});
$("#Square").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "white");
});
$("#Triangle").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
});
$("#Triangle").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "white");
});
$(c).mousedown(function() {
  makeCircle();
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <canvas id = 'board' height = "600" width = "800" style="border:1px solid black";></canvas>
            <head>
        <title> Shape Drawing </title>
    <div id = "links">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "functions.js"></script>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = stylesheet href="main.css">

    </div>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id = "shapes_title"> Shapes:</h1> 
        <div id = "buttons">
        <button id = 'Circle' onclick="circleTrue()"> Circle </button>
        <button id = "Square" onclick ="squareTrue()"> Square </button>
        <button id = "Triangle" onclick="triangleTrue"> Triangle </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```